# Merge list of lists into one list in a pyspark using the UDF function

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have dataframe

```
data = [("2021-01", "h1", [["t1", "t2"], ["t3", "t2"]], ["u1", "u2"], [{"u1":3}, {"u2":2}]),
        ("2021-02", "h1", [["t4"], ["t5", "t6", "t7"]], ["u4", "u3"], [{"u4":3}, {"u3":1}])]

df = spark.createDataFrame(data, ["date", "list_hash", "list_text", "list_userid", "groups_ids"])
+-------+---------+--------------------+-----------+--------------------+  
|date   |list_hash|list_text           |list_userid|groups_ids          |  
+-------+---------+--------------------+-----------+--------------------+  
|2021-01|h1       |[[t1, t2], [t3, t2]]|[u1, u2]   |[{"u1":3}, {"u2":2}]|  
|2021-02|h1       |[[t4], [t5, t6, t7]]|[u4, u3]   |[{"u4":3}, {"u3":1}]|  
+-------+---------+--------------------+-----------+--------------------+
```

I need to combine a list of lists into one list. I don't want to use explode and then groupby. So I created udf function:

```
class udf_annotator:
    def __init__(self, returnType: DataType = StringType()):
        self.spark_udf_type = returnType

    def __call__(self, func: Callable):
        @functools.wraps(func)
        def wrapped_func(*args, **kwargs):
            if any([isinstance(arg, F.column) for arg in args]) or \
                    any([isinstance(vv, F.column) for vv in kwargs.values()]):
                return udf(func, self.spark_udf_type)(*args, **kwargs)
            else:
                return func(*args, **kwargs)
        return wrapped_func

@udf_annotator(returnType=ArrayType(StringType()))
def flattenDistinctList(list_column):
    flat_list = []
    for l in list_column:
        if isinstance(l, list):
            flat_list.extend(l)
    return list(set(flat_list))
```

But it's not working. I am expecting the following result:

```
-------+---------+----------------+-----------+--------------------+
|date   |list_hash|list_text       |list_userid|groups_ids          |
+-------+---------+----------------+-----------+--------------------+
|2021-01|h1       |[t1, t2, t3, t2]|[u1, u2]   |[{"u1":3}, {"u2":2}]|
|2021-02|h1       |[t4, t5, t6, t7]|[u4, u3]   |[{"u4":3}, {"u3":1}]|
+-------+---------+----------------+-----------+--------------------+
```

Comment: Please add your expected output.

Comment: @Rory I updated my answer with comments about workability of your udf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I get your properly, instead of creating custom udf, you can use [`flatten`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/pyspark.sql/api/pyspark.sql.functions.flatten.html#pyspark.sql.functions.flatten) function

Example:

```
df.select(
    flatten("list_text")
)
```

---

You deleted your question under my answer, about workability about your udf, but I checked it anyway, the problem is that your check `any([isinstance(arg, F.column) for arg in args])` is always false.

1st problem is it doesn't compile at all, I made it compile by changing:

`any([isinstance(arg, F.column) for arg in args])` => `any([isinstance(arg, type(F.column)) for arg in args])`

After that I was able to test it and check result schema like this

```
df.select(
    flattenDistinctList("list_text")
).schema
```

Output was: `StructType(List())`, so it's defenitely not what your expecting, but this schema may appear if `else` branch was triggered inside your `udf_annotator`.

So, it means that problem is in your type checking.
You can test your type like this:

```
test_arg = [F.lit('col_name')]
any([isinstance(arg, type(F.column)) for arg in test_arg])
```

and result will be `false`, because type of `type(F.column)` is `function`, so you need any object of type column to force check work properly, you can do it like this:

```
test_arg = [F.lit('col_name')]
any([isinstance(arg, type(F.lit('a'))) for arg in test_arg])
```

Now, the output of this check will be `true`.

So, to make your code work it's enough to change:

`any([isinstance(arg, F.column) for arg in args])` => `any([isinstance(arg, type(F.lit('a'))) for arg in args])`
(the same with kwargs)

But with this minimal changes your code will work only if your pass column explicitly to your udf, like this:

```
df.select(
    flattenDistinctList(F.col("list_text")),
).show()
```

But if you pass it as string, it won't work

```
df.select(
    flattenDistinctList("list_text"),
).show()
```

Also don't forget that using python udf with spark can have significant impact on performance of your job. Read more about this [here](https://medium.com/quantumblack/spark-udf-deep-insights-in-performance-f0a95a4d8c62)

Comment: Okay, now I understand. Didn't notice an error.